# Cannot work Language change button using i18next in react

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I want to Change language When Click Button using i18next.
Below is my source code and When click button cannot change Language.
Please can tell me what i need to fix.
I already import import './i18n'; at index.js.

i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use (initReactI18next)
    .init({
        // default/fallback language
        fallbackLng: 'ja',
        ns: ["default"],
        defaultNS: "default",
        useSuspense: false,
        //detects and caches a cookie from the language provided
        react: {
            useSuspense: false,
            wait: false,
        },
        detection: {
            order: ['queryString', 'cookie'],
            cache: ['cookie']
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        },
    })

export default i18n;
```

Nav.js

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const Nav = () => {
    const [t, i18n] = useTranslation();
    const currentRoute = useHistory().location.pathname.toLowerCase();
    return (
        <div className="tab-bar">
            <label className="logo">{t("FPF Support Tool")}</label>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                <button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage("ja")}>
                    日本
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage("en")}>
                    英語
                </button>
            </div>
        )
       }
```

Comment: What’s the console output if you set debug to true?
Maybe compare with this example: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/react/src/App.js#L37

Comment: @adrai Thank you so much. i need init resources at i18n.js file